# Compile for Chromebook using Crouton

Tags: c, gcc, chroot, chromebook, crouton-os

I currently have an Asus c300 chromebook. Since it doesn't have legacy boot, I'm using crouton to get a more standard command line environment. I was able to install gcc very easily in the chroot environment. It works very well under chroot.

Since the underlying hardware is the same, I thought the resulting executable should work for chromebook, without me being in the chroot environment. If true, I thought I could go into the chroot environment, compile whatever program I want/need, and exit back out to the regular environment and use it.

I tried it with a simple hello world program. When I tried to run the executable, I got the following error:

```
bash: ./a.out: Permission denied.
```

I tried to run it with sudo, and I get a similar error:

```
sudo: unable to execute ./a.out: Permission denied.
```

I even used su to login as root, and I still could not run the program (got the first error).

I thought su/sudo would override any kind of permission restriction. But, it's apparently not the case on the chromebook.

What am I missing? Is what I want to do possible?

EDIT: File permission was already set to 777.

Answer (score 0):

You might simply have to change the permissions of the file or check the files ownership.  umask determines weather or not a file that is created gets execute permissions by default.  What does -ls -lat on the file reveal?

Also try running

```
chmod +x ./a.out
```

Comment: What about ldd on the binary could it be some of the libraries it loads have different permissions?

Comment: Output from ldd under chroot:

    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffea0895000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8553d5c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f855413a000).

I don't have ldd in the regular shell. However, I was not able to find /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 in normal environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details of error with `strace` command
use:
`strace ./a.out` and check output.
I suppose you have different `env (path and LD_library_path)` under the `chroot`.

Comment: I don't have strace under regular environment, so I can't compare the outputs.